# Getting FileNotFoundException when pass jrxml file to JasperFillManager.fillReport

Tags: java, servlets, jasper-reports, filenotfoundexception

Its working perfectly when I check the preview and give a parameter using eclipse but doesn't when I try to pass it via the servlet.... I intend to accept an input from the user via HTML and pass it onto the Servlet

Extra Info: The query is defined in the jrxml file and a connection is provided too

Not a duplicate to:  [Where to place a .txt file so that a java servlet can read it during runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4410890/where-to-place-a-txt-file-so-that-a-java-servlet-can-read-it-during-runtime)

More info after first stack trace

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
```

Code I'm concerned with

```
        HashMap map = new HashMap();
        JasperPrint jasperPrint = null;
        Connection connection = null;
        map.put("uLimit","2"); 
        try {
            jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport("Ticket.jrxml",map,connection);

        } catch (JRException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Error:

```
net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: Ticket.jrxml
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.util.JRLoader.loadObject(JRLoader.java:110)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.util.JRLoader.loadObject(JRLoader.java:99)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperFillManager.fill(JasperFillManager.java:272)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperFillManager.fillReport(JasperFillManager.java:745)
    at com.sjr.controller.TicketReport.doGet(TicketReport.java:46)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:624)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:505)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:169)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:956)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:423)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1079)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:625)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:318)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
```

I tried

```
String Path=getServletContext().getRealPath("/WebContent/Ticket.jrxml");

jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(Path,map,connection);
```

StackTrace

```
net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\dilip new woorkspace 3-19-2016\DJ_Party_2.0\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps\DJPartyManagement vC\WebContent\Ticket.jrxml
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.util.JRLoader.loadObject(JRLoader.java:110)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.util.JRLoader.loadObject(JRLoader.java:99)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperFillManager.fill(JasperFillManager.java:272)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperFillManager.fillReport(JasperFillManager.java:745)
    at com.sjr.controller.TicketReport.doGet(TicketReport.java:54)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:624)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:505)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:169)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:956)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:423)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1079)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:625)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:316)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\dilip new woorkspace 3-19-2016\DJ_Party_2.0\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps\DJPartyManagement vC\WebContent\Ticket.jrxml
    ... 27 more
```

And

```
String Path =(getServletContext().getContextPath()+"/Ticket.jrxml");
```

StackTrace

```
net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: \DJPartyManagement_vC\Ticket.jrxml
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.util.JRLoader.loadObject(JRLoader.java:110)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.util.JRLoader.loadObject(JRLoader.java:99)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperFillManager.fill(JasperFillManager.java:272)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperFillManager.fillReport(JasperFillManager.java:745)
    at com.sjr.controller.TicketReport.doGet(TicketReport.java:54)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:624)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:505)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:169)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:956)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:423)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1079)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:625)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:316)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: \DJPartyManagement_vC\Ticket.jrxml
    ... 27 more
```

And

```
InputStream Path = getServletContext().getResourceAsStream("/Ticket.jrxml");
```

StackTrace

```
net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException: Error loading object from InputStream
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.util.JRLoader.loadObject(JRLoader.java:249)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.util.JRLoader.loadObject(JRLoader.java:229)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperFillManager.fill(JasperFillManager.java:405)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperFillManager.fillReport(JasperFillManager.java:824)
    at com.sjr.controller.TicketReport.doGet(TicketReport.java:55)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:624)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:505)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:169)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:956)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:423)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1079)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:625)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:316)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.io.StreamCorruptedException: invalid stream header: 3C3F786D
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readStreamHeader(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.util.ContextClassLoaderObjectInputStream.<init>(ContextClassLoaderObjectInputStream.java:58)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.util.JRLoader.loadObject(JRLoader.java:244)
    ... 26 more
```

Thank You for reading....

Comment: You must show the root cause. You cut off the stack trace just before the root cause.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Where to place a .txt file so that a java servlet can read it during runtime](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4410890/where-to-place-a-txt-file-so-that-a-java-servlet-can-read-it-during-runtime)

Comment: Nope.... I tried the above solution..... Didn't work

Comment: Duplicate of [Error Occured in jasperReport File](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19975718/876298)

Comment: You forgot to tell where exactly that file is located in the project/WAR structure. Nonetheless, this has most likely the answer/explanation you're looking for: http://stackoverflow.com/q/2161054